# How to add Symfony 5 command with EntityManager injection to console app

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I added injection EntityManagerInterface to my command constructor

```
# Class MyCommand
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
    parent::__construct();
}
```

but I do not understand how to add my command to Application because it has a new arg now

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$app = new Application();
$app->add(new MyCommand($entityManager)); // where is $entityManager defined ?
```

How can I get defined $entityManager? Or I must define it somewhere because it does not bootstrapping automatically with Symfony?

Comment: The easiest approach is to just use the Symfony framework.  But if you are looking for a strictly standalone command then it is indeed up to you to configure and instantiate the entity manager.  It is not part of the console library.  The doctrine docs have the details.

Comment: Thank you. I understood. I need to use Symfony Kernel class at fist and Kernel::boot() method.

Comment: Don't know what the Kernel has to do with your question but you are welcome.  Just seems if you already have the Kernel code installed then you probably have the framework as well.  In which case you would not be interacting directly with the Application class.